# Java: Json Response classcast exception

Tags: java, json, httpresponse

I have created a http GET response parser where I can get the keys and values of my json data and input it into a tableRow object but I receive an java.lang.ClassCastException

Here is my JsonResponse from my URL:

```
{"vulnerability":{"id":15017916,"status":"open","closed_at":null,"created_at":"2019-07-26T10:06:03Z","due_date":null,"notes":null,"port":[],"priority":null,"identifiers":["adobe-flash-apsb14-21-cve-2014-0556"],"last_seen_time":"2019-07-24T06:00:00.000Z","fix_id":691,"scanner_vulnerabilities":[{"port":null,"external_unique_id":"adobe-flash-apsb14-21-cve-2014-0556","open":true}],"asset_id":291633,"connectors":[{"id":7,"name":"Nexpose Enterprise","connector_definition_name":"Nexpose Enterprise","vendor":"Rapid7"}],"service_ticket":null,"urls":{"asset":"api.nyc3.us.kennasecurity.com/assets/291633"},"patch":true,"patch_published_at":"2014-09-11T07:57:40.000Z","cve_id":"CVE-2014-0556","cve_description":"Heap-based buffer overflow in Adobe Flash Player before 13.0.0.244 and 14.x and 15.x before 15.0.0.152 on Windows and OS X and before 11.2.202.406 on Linux, Adobe AIR before 15.0.0.249 on Windows and OS X and before 15.0.0.252 on Android, Adobe AIR SDK before 15.0.0.249, and Adobe AIR SDK & Compiler before 15.0.0.249 allows attackers to execute arbitrary code via unspecified vectors, a different vulnerability than CVE-2014-0559.","cve_published_at":"2014-09-10T01:55:00.000Z","description":null,"solution":null,"wasc_id":null,"severity":10,"threat":10,"popular_target":false,"active_internet_breach":true,"easily_exploitable":true,"malware_exploitable":true,"predicted_exploitable":false,"custom_fields":[],"first_found_on":"2019-07-24T06:27:26Z","top_priority":true,"risk_meter_score":100,"closed":false}}
```

Here is my parser method:

```
public static TableRow parseRequest(String request, TableRow row) {
        JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
//throws an exception here      JsonArray jsonArray =  (JsonArray) jsonParser.parse(request);

        // this object is used to get the keys
        com.google.gson.JsonObject firstJsonObject = jsonArray.get(0).getAsJsonObject();        
        java.util.Set<Entry<String,JsonElement>> entrySet = firstJsonObject.entrySet();

        // declare two dimensional array
        Object[][] array = new Object[entrySet.size()][jsonArray.size() + 1];

        // the first column of the two-dimensional array is populated
        Iterator<java.util.Map.Entry<String, JsonElement>> itr = entrySet.iterator();
        for (int i = 0; itr.hasNext(); i++) {
            array[i][0] = itr.next().getKey();
        }

        // the rest of the columns are populated
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.size(); i++) {
            com.google.gson.JsonObject obj = (com.google.gson.JsonObject) jsonArray.get(i);
            for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
                String key = array[j][0].toString();
                JsonElement value = (JsonElement) obj.get(key);
                array[j][i + 1] = value instanceof JsonNull ? null : value.getAsString();
            }

        }
        return row;
```

I do not  know how to necessarily go forward here. any suggestions to remedy this error?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to cast JsonParser to a JsonArray. This is not possible since JsonArray is not a subclass(it doesn't extends nor it implements JsonParser). What you probably want to do is cast JsonParser to an object, as below. After that, you can get the array by identifying, from your JSON, the keyword.

```
JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) parser.parse(request);

//Obtain the array from the keyword in your JSON.
JSONArray zoneArray = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("KeywordForTheArray");
```

Happy Coding!

Comment: thank you for your help but now I am receiving a different kind of error which is  java.lang.NullPointerException  at com.google.gson.JsonObject firstJsonObject = jsonArray.get(0).getAsJsonObject();

Comment: You need to post your JSON to help you further.

Comment: I have posted the json now